# Why do HM-10 peripheral characteristic FFE1 properties not include writeWithoutResponse when queried via distriqt BluetoothLE ANE?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ane, distriqt, hm-10

I am developing with Apache Flex 4.15, Adobe AIR, distriqt BluetoothLE ANE, iPhone4S, Arduino and the HM-10 Bluetooth LE module.  When I test the HM-10 with the LightBlue app, it shows the expected single service (uuid FFE0) with a single characteristic (FFE1).  The characteristic's properties are read, writeWithoutResponse and notify.  I am able to read and write bytes as expected between the iPhone4S and the Arduino.

However, when I query the HM-10 via the distriqt BluetoothLE ANE, I get the same service and characteristic uuids, but the returned characteristic's properties include only read and notify.  Of course I get an error if I try to write to it.

What would cause this difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have done some investigation over the weekend and it appears this is an issue in the ANE.

Characteristics are always reported to have only the read and notify properties.

I have identified the cause and will start on the fix but if you can log this as an issue with the ANE and we will follow up in the issue tracker with you.